# Windows 8 App Store - Navigation issue

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I'm having an issue with a Windows 8 App Store application that I'm trying to write.
I'm trying to navigate to a new page. I'm using this code in my MainViewModel:

```
var page = (Window.Current.Content as Frame); 
page.Navigate(typeof(Home));
```

Then in my HomeViewModel I'm trying to access the Home view so that I could get some stuff to work, I'm using this code:

```
var page = (LayoutAwarePage)(Window.Current.Content);
```

When I run my application it tells me:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and when I place my mouse over

> Window.Current

, I see it is set to

> NULL

... So how is this possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you might need to do is to move the code that references the 'Home' page in Home.xaml.cs instead of in HomeViewModel.cs. Call a method in HomeViewModel.cs from Home.xaml.cs - hope this helps. (I am assuming your HomeViewModel.cs is a class, which you'll probably need to instantiate in Home.xaml.cs)